# How to add Subpartition to all partitions

Tags: oracle, partitioning, oracle-11g, alter-table

I believe adding sub-partition in `Oracle 11g` is easy

```
ALTER TABLE PART_TEST
modify partition OCT19
add subpartition OCT19AXCS
values ('AXCS');
```

I have close to `250` partitions..namely

```
jan07
feb07
...
up till
...
dec26
```

Does it mean I need to include that many alter table statements to alter all my partitions and add sub-partitions ?

Comment: @JSapkota I used sub-partition template at the time of initial table creation. So I guess I need to alter the complete template with newly added sub-partition..hmm
No direct way to simply add only that sub-partition...OK

Comment: @JSapkota That does not affect existing partitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just easily loop through the partitions in a PL/SQL loop, and add the subpartitions:

```
begin
  for p in (select partition_name from user_tab_partitions where table_name = 'PART_TEST')
  loop
    execute immediate 'alter table part_test modify partition ' || p.partition_name || ' add subpartition ' || p.partition_name || 'AXCS values (''AXCS'')'; 
  end loop;
end;
/
```